# snap svg animate from Illustrator file

Tags: animation, snap.svg

I've got an svg file from Illustrator that I pasted into an html file; I am trying to animate it with snap svg.
The following causes no errors, but doesn't move anything either. I tried changing the value, and also animating other attributes, but nothing doing. I also tried adding a callback function as some suggest.

```
var svg = Snap("#svg");
var ball = svg.select("#ball")
var mov = ball.animate({x: 10}, 1000);
console.log(mov);
```

The `ball` object looks like this:

```
  <path id="ball" d="M100.5,123A38.5,38.5,0,1,0,139,161.5,38.5,38.5,0,0,0,100.5,123Zm17,28a4.5,4.5,0,1,1,4.5-4.5A4.49,4.49,0,0,1,117.5,151Z" transform="translate(0 557)" style="fill: red"/>
```

The log of the `mov` object in the console looks like this:

```
Object { node: path#ball, paper: {…}, type: "path", id: "pathSjdy9zk8k1", anims: {…}, _: {…} }
```

Comment: A path doesn't have an 'x' attribute, so don't animate that :). Animate the transform instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Started trying to code but the object disappears, for ex: var mov = ball.animate({"transform" : "t123 t123"}, 1500); If I understand correctly, you have to understand what a matrix is before trying to move anything. Will return later.

Comment: Was related to the viewport, now I see it moving.